# undefined local variable or method 'main_page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my **application.html.erb** I have a menu, which is displayed on every page. But I can't use 'sign out' link, an error appears.

> undefined local variable or method 'main_page'

I have 'main_page' in my routes and I don't understand why it's not working. 
I've tried to use 'sign out' link from my show view in the User controller's action, and it worked fine.

**show.html**

```
<% content_for :user_form do %>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= @user.email %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(@user) %> 
<%= link_to 'My dates', :controller => :calendar, :action => :month_for_user %>
<%= link_to 'sign out', :controller => :sessions, :action => :destroy %>
<%end%>
```

Why there is an error when the link is used from application.html? Although 'My dates' link works. How can I fix it?

**application.html**

```
<div id = 'user_menu' >

  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= current_user.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Email:</strong>
  <%= current_user.email %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(current_user) %> 
<%= link_to 'My dates', :controller => 'calendar', :action => 'month_for_user' %>
<%= link_to 'sign out', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy' %>


<% end %>

  </div>
```

**sessions_controller**

```
def destroy
    redirect_to main_page
    sign_out
end
```

**routes**

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
      meetings GET    /meetings(.:format)          meetings#index
               POST   /meetings(.:format)          meetings#create
   new_meeting GET    /meetings/new(.:format)      meetings#new
  edit_meeting GET    /meetings/:id/edit(.:format) meetings#edit
       meeting GET    /meetings/:id(.:format)      meetings#show
               PATCH  /meetings/:id(.:format)      meetings#update
               PUT    /meetings/:id(.:format)      meetings#update
               DELETE /meetings/:id(.:format)      meetings#destroy
      new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
         users GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
     main_page GET    /main_page(.:format)         welcome#domain
   new_session GET    /sign_in(.:format)           sessions#new
       signout GET    /sign_out(.:format)          sessions#destroy
      sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)          sessions#create
               GET    /sessions/new(.:format)      sessions#new
  edit_session GET    /sessions/:id/edit(.:format) sessions#edit
       session PATCH  /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
               PUT    /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#update
               DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)      sessions#destroy
               GET    /sessions/:id(.:format)      welcome#domain
               GET    /users(.:format)             users#index
               POST   /users(.:format)             users#create
               GET    /users/new(.:format)         users#new
     edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)    users#edit
          user GET    /users/:id(.:format)         users#show
               PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
               PUT    /users/:id(.:format)         users#update
               DELETE /users/:id(.:format)         users#destroy
month_for_user GET    /month_for_user(.:format)    calendar#month_for_user
```

Rails is new for me, and maybe it's a silly question, but I honestly tried to find an answer unfortunately without results. Please, help me to fix this problem! Thank you

Comment: have you created a view for main_page?
I dont see it in your code provided

Comment: My answer should solve your current problem, but what is `sign_out` in the `destroy` method? If its just a variable which is not defined, then again you will get another error.

Comment: sign_out is okay, it's a method in a helper. ) It works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> undefined local variable or method 'main_page'

The error comes from the `destroy` method in your `sessions_controller`. It should be

```
def destroy
  redirect_to main_page_url #or action: "main_page"
  sign_out 
end
```